# can i set a 301 redirect into a rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess

Can i set a 301 redirect into a rewrite rule?

eg can i set a 301 redirect into this code?

```
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html(.*)$ /product.php?id_product=$2&isolang=$1$4 [L,E]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want Apache to treat your static URL as something your PHP script is interested in, you should not need to set a 301 response code for your static page. A 3xx response code is only used when you're redirecting somebody from page A to page B with a change in the URL.